# php apache (xampp) odbc connection issue

Tags: php, apache, sql-server

When I run apache (via xampp) as a standalone server not as a service (on Windows Server 2008)

with the following connection code everything works fine (username and password removed )

```
$server = "WMS";
$link  = odbc_connect($server,'','');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went horribly wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}else {echo('');}
```

If however I change apache to run as a service in Windows the connection breaks and I get the following error message

```
    Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Dev\well.php on line 30

     Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read documentation: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

`$server = "WMS";` suggests that you have ODBC alias/data source configured with that name. Error message clearly says that data source with such name (WMS) is not found. On Windows 7/Vista/XP/Server you can configure them at "Start -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)" -- *path can be different on older OS*. In any case -- look for "Microsoft ODBC Data Source Administrator".

Instead of using alias, I would recommend (the way I always connect) to use full DSN name, e.g.

```
// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver - allows connection to SQL 7, 2000, 2005 and 2008
$link = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
```

In this case everything is part of the script and no external dependencies.

BTW -- instead of using ODBC Functions, I would recommend using **PDO** & driver specially for MS SQL Server: **PDO_SQLSRV** -- http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php (or **Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP** if you prefer old procedural style -- http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php )

Comment: I do have a DATA source (ODBC) setup with the name WMS, I think that's how its working now because if I change `$server = "WMS";` to something else it doesn't connect (when apache is running not as a service) perhaps I need the driver info in the odbc_connect line I will try

Comment: also I am using SQL server 2012 does that line also apply to 2012? or should I be doign something different?

Comment: I'm using the line below to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2, as well as SQL Server 2005 (it all depends on SQL Server Native Client version you have - mine is from SQL Server 2008) -- as far as I know the connection string should be the same for 2012 version. `'Provider=SQLNCLI10;SERVER='.CFG_DB_SERVER.';UID='.CFG_DB_LOGIN.';PWD='.CFG_DB_PASSWORD.';DATABASE='.CFG_DB_DATABASE.';'`

Comment: Small correction -- if using Native Client from 2012, the Provider should be `SQLNCLI11` -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131291.aspx

Comment: `// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver - allows connection to SQL 7, 2000, 2005 and 2008
$link = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;",$user,$password); `Works for me now, but I was tring to use windows authentication, and needed to setup SQL Server as the authentication method and setup a user in the login table in SQL Server 2012

Comment: You can use windows authentication here as well -- omit user name and password; add `Integrated Security=SSPI;` to the connection string - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008